# cakephp pagination only sorting on some columns

Tags: cakephp, pagination, cakephp-1.3

I have the following code in a controller.  I can sort by all fields except `Claim.number` and `Payer.abbr`.  Anyone see why that might be?

```
$this->paginate = array(
    'fields' => array(
        'PaymentException.*', 'Procedure.id', 'Procedure.cpt',
        'Procedure.expected_amount', 'Procedure.allowed_amount', 'Procedure.difference_amount',
        'Claim.id', 'Claim.number', 'Payer.abbr'
    ),
    'limit' => 50,
    'joins' => array(
        array(
            'table' => 'procedures',
            'alias' => 'Procedure',
            'conditions' => array('Procedure.id = PaymentException.procedure_id')
            ),
        array(
            'table' => 'claims',
            'alias' => 'Claim',
            'conditions' => array('Claim.id = Procedure.claim_id')
        ),
        array(
            'table' => 'payers',
            'alias' => 'Payer',
            'conditions' => array('Payer.id = Procedure.payer_id')
        ),
        array(
            'table' => 'groups',
            'alias' => 'Groups',
            'conditions' => array('Groups.id = Claim.group_id')
        ),
    array(
        'table' => 'exception_workflow_logs',
        'alias' => 'ExceptionWorkflowLog',
        'conditions' => array('ExceptionWorkflowLog.exception_id = PaymentException.id')
    )
    ),
    'conditions' => $conditions
);
```

All of the fields have been done in the view like:

`<?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Claim', 'Claim.number'); ?>`

I see them in the URL, but it never sorts by `Claim.number` or `Payer.abbr`.  I don't see why that would be.

In my conditions array I have:

```
array
  0 => string 'Procedure.difference_amount < 0' (length=31)
  1 => string 'PaymentException.finalized IS NULL' (length=34)
```

Note that the conditions array stays the same even on the columns that sort properly.

Comment: Get the sql generated and make sure it's correct. Try running that query in phpmyadmin or another tool to see if it works.

Comment: Looking at the SQL output, it is not correct.  I'm trying to sort by `Claim.number` and there is no `ORDER BY` in the output.

Comment: What is in $conditions array ?

Comment: Updated question to include conditions array

Answer (score 1):

You cant use joins and containable together. You will need to remove the contain and use a join or fetch the records for the contain in a second query.

Comment: Sorry to remove the green check mark, but this actually doesn't work.  I've removed the contain and made it a join, and I'm seeing the exact same thing.  Anything I can do to debug?